# Pegar ID do post com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Preciso pegar o `id` da tag HTML gerado dinamicamente pelo WordPress.

O WordPress tem a opção de adicionar o ID do post na tag HTML assim:
[image: article id]

Como faço para pegar o ID que fica dentro da tag `<article>` com JavaScript, sendo que ele não é fixo?

Comment: você quer obter o valor do atributo id ou o elemento com id 72?

Comment: acho que vc consegue pegar dessa forma: const element = document.getElementById('representatives-list').children[0];

Comment: `getElementById` obtém apenas os elementos com id especificado nesse caso `representatives-list` é uma classe e não um ID, então pode-se usar `document.querySelectorAll('.type-representantes')[0]`

Comment: Por curiosidade, como é o PHP que gera essa página? Não é mais fácil utilizar a função `get_the_ID()` para pegar o id da publicação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aqui tem uma forma bem simples. Quando vc clica no `article` ele te retorna o `ID` que está nele. Eu usei o `querySelectorAll` para pegar qq `article`, e no `forEach` eu chama uma função que retorno o `ID` do elemento clicado no console, mas ali vc pode colocar qq tipo de função...

```js
var meuID = document.querySelectorAll('article');

function quemEH(el) {
   var nome = el.currentTarget.id;
    console.log(nome)
}
meuID.forEach( (artigo) => {
    artigo.addEventListener('click', quemEH);
})
```

```html
<article id="n1">article com ID n1</article>
<article id="n2">article com ID n2</article>
```

Answer (score 4):

Para pegar uma lista com todos os IDs dos elementos que tenham classe que se inicia com `post-`, basta fazer algo assim:

```js
const postIds = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('article[class*="post-"]')
).map((el) => el.id);

console.log(postIds);
```

```html
<article id="1" class="post-1"></article>
<article id="2" class="post-2"></article>
<article id="3" class="post-3"></article>
<article id="4" class="post-4"></article>
<article id="5" class="post-5"></article>
```

Note que se você puder garantir que a classe `post-` sempre virá primeiro, você pode trocar o seletor `article[class*="post-"]` por `article[class^="post-"]` para ter um pequeno ganho na performance.

Comment: Não é mt boa essa ideia porque a ordem das classes podem ser alteradas.

Comment: @Sam, e isso é um problema? O autor não menciona isso na pergunta...

Comment: Provavelmente é, porque o HTML é gerado dinamicamente e não existe a garantia que `post-72` será a primeira classe do elemento. Se for algo como `categoria post-72` essa solução já não funciona. Basicamente você fica dependente de uma situação que não tem controle.

Comment: Ahhh sim, agora entendi o problema...

Comment: Editei a resposta... É um pouco menos performático, mas acaba abrangendo todos os casos. :)

Answer (score 2):

Pegue a div pai pela classe e depois o elemento pela tag `article` e enfim o atributo `id`:

```js
var id = document.getElementsByClassName("representatives-list")[0]
.getElementsByTagName("article")[0]
.getAttribute("id");
console.log(id);
```

```html
<div class="representatives-list">
   <article id="72"></article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que será possível através pesquisa por elementos por className, por exemplo:

```
document.getElementByClassName("representative-list")[0].getElementByClassName("post72")
```

Comment: Pode simplificar para `document.querySelector(".representative-list .post-72")`, mas nesse caso você precisaria ainda ter conhecimento da classe `.post-72`, que é justamente o id da publicação.